# What shebang/command can be used in a python script so that it will bypass password prompt when I run a sudo shell commands?

Tags: python, shell, automation, passwords, shebang

I am using the script for automation purpose. so when i run python script it would execute a series of shell commands with sudo for root access. I am using subprocess and os.system to execute these commands. But when I run the script it prompts to enter password and only after password is entered will execute the command. How can I resolve this so that password prompt is evaded?

I don't know exactly what commands I need to execute or need to be present with the python script in linux so that for root access password won't be asked. Please support for this issue

Comment: This is not something you put in the script, it's something you configure in `/etc/sudoers`

Comment: Here is a quick reference on the [sudoers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt)